# How can I fit my iframe in the entire page instead of using the scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I was wondering how I can fit my iframe into the entire page instead fo having a scrollbar. The height is set to 100% and the iframe load correctly. But when it loads it loads with a scrollbar instead of covering the whole page. Here is the example in jsfiddle

```
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%; 
}

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp"><iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4W29G/10/

How can I fit my iframe into the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

On HTML try adding scrolling="no":

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp" scrolling="no"><iframe>
```

And on CSS:

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 

  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the iframe to take over whole page and cover all the original content?

Comment: What browsers do you use?

Comment: No just to fit......    http://jsfiddle.net/4W29G/15/      ....notice entire content does not appear it gets cut off